# random gausian number in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate two 10^12_by_1 random matrices in MATLAB. I used

> randn

but it generates correlated random numbers. How can I generate these matrices so that they don't get correlated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Several comments:

1. Generating 10^12 random doubles at once almost certainly isn't possible since 10^12 doubles would be 8*10^12 bytes, that is, 1000 gigabytes. Your machine almost certainly has nowhere near that amount of RAM.
2. If the question is, "How do I generate a vector containing `n` independent draws from the standard normal distribution?" the answer would be to use `x = randn(n, 1);`
3. If the default pseudo random number generator isn't functioning well for your particular problem, you could investigate other options [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/random-number-generation.html).
4. In my experience, most of the time people complain about pseudo random number generation libraries, the actual problem is the programmer's buggy code or that the programmer has incorrect beliefs about what should happen.

Comment: 1- how about 10^8 numbers?

Comment: 3_ my problem is that randn generates correlated random numbers when n is large.

Comment: Why do you think they are correlated? What specifically is wrong?

Comment: because i calculate correlation between numbers. my simple random walker walk in asymmetric way too.

Comment: all of functions you introduced in part 3 have this problem,.

Comment: @Mehrana How do you calculate correlation? What precisely do you do? What specifically happens which you think is wrong?

Comment: my code for random walkerbetween 2 planes in y=0 and y=5 is as below:  @matthew gunn                                                                                              clc;
clear;
    y(1) = 0;
    x(1) =0 ;
    
 for i = 2:2000000
        x(i) = x(i-1) + randn(1,1);
        y(i) = y(i-1) + randn(1,1);
        if(y(i) <= 0 || y(i)>5)
        x(i) = x(i-1);
        y(i)= y(i-1);
        end
     end
mean(x)

Comment: and this code dosn't work good. because trajectory of walker is not symmetric in x direction

Comment: Huh? I still don't see what's wrong from a random standpoint. In my testing, x goes up about 42% of the time, goes down about 42% of the time, and stays constant about 16% of the time (because y hit the barrier). mean(x) of course tends to show larger and larger numbers as n increases because x is still similar to a random walk and wanders off infinitely in either direction. Your problem almost certainly IS NOT random number generation; I think your beliefs about what should happen are not correct.

Comment: @mehrana mean(x) should not converge towards anything as n increases; it should wander off towards positive or negative infinity. On the other hand, mean(diff(x)) should go towards zero, and it does. x is not stationary! but the first difference of x is stationary.

Comment: please plot(x,y) after running the program. you will understand that random numbers have problem. @Mattew Gunn

Comment: also you can calculate sum(diff(x)). i expect this number to be zero. but it is  very large positive number.

Comment: @Mehrana You are wrong. sum(diff(x)) should not be zero. it should not converge to zero as n increases. mean(diff(x)) should converge to zero as n increases.

Comment: Did you plot(x,y)?

Comment: sum(diff(x)) should be zero. because of the symmetry. it should not be large positive or negative number. because the portion of positive and negative steps must be equal.

Comment: @Mehrana You are wrong and should review your probability. Go flip a coin 10 times and see if you get an equal number of heads or tails. Flip a coin 100 times and see if you get an equal number of heads or tails. Flip it 1000 times. Flip it 2 million times and you'll be very far from zero! The more coin flips you do, the further away, on average, the sum will be from zero.